# How is ちん working in 知らんちん

Tags: words

While watching [Cowboy Bebop](https://anjsub.com/watch-cowboy-bebop/?v=episode13) I came across aa short dialog between the woman bounty hunter and the little girl:

21:12みんなでどこ行ってきたの？

21:15いい所よ

21:16エドだけ知らんちん

It is the last part in which the girl says エドだけ知らんちん that ちん draws my attention. Why does she use it? Is it an emphasiser?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a variant of わからんちん, which is a rare, funny, a little childish way to say わからん ("I dunno" or "It's all Greek to me"). This ちん has no important meaning, but one may think it's a kind of [dimunitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive). わからんちん seems to be common in some areas, but no one used it in the area where I was born. I probably heard わからんちん for the first time at the [opening of an anime called 一休さん](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxDR0lT2pLk&feature=youtu.be&t=62).

(ちん is also a rare dialectal suffix used in a part of Kyushu, but I'm not sure if it's related to this.)